# Monitoring Thread performance of server

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, pipe, monitoring

I have developed a C server using gcc and pthreads that receives UDP packets and depending on the configuration either drops or forwards them to specific targets. In some cases these packets are untouched and just redirected, in some cases headers in the packet are modified, in other cases there is another module of the server that modifies every byte of the packet.

To configure this server, there is a GUI written in Java that connects to the C Server using TCP (to exchange configuration commands). There can be multiple connected GUIs at the same time.

In order to measure utilization of the server I have written kind of a module that starts two separate threads (#2 & #3). The main thread (#1) that does the whole forwarding work essentially works like the following:

```
struct monitoring_struct data; //contains 2 * uint64_t for start and end time among other fields
for(;;){
    recvfrom();
    data.start = current_time();
    modifyPacket();
    sendPacket(); //sometimes to multiple destinations
    data.end = current_time();
    writeDataToPipe();
}
```

The current_time function:

```
 //give a timestamp in microsecond precision
    uint64_t current_time(void){
        struct timespec spec;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);
        uint64_t ts = (uint64_t) ((((double) spec.tv_sec) * 1.0e6) +
 (((double) spec.tv_nsec) / 1.0e3));
        return ts;
    }
```

As indicated in the main thread, the data struct is written into a pipe, where thread #2 waits to read from. Everytime there is data to be read from the pipe, thread #2 uses a given aggregation function that stores the data in another place in memory. Thread #3 is a loop, that always sleeps for ~1 sec and then sends out the aggregated values (median, avg, min, max, lower quartil, upper quartil, ...) and then resets the aggregated data. Thread #2 and #3 are synchronized by mutexes.

The GUI listens to this data (if the monitoring window is open) which is sent out via UDP to listeners (there can be more) and the GUI then converts the numbers into diagrams, graphs and "pressure" indicators.

I came up with this as this is in my mind the solution that interferes least of all with thread #1 (assuming that it is run on a multicore system, which it always is, and exclusively besides OS and maybe SSH).

As performance is critical for my server (version "1.0" with simpler configuration was able to manage the maximum amount of streams that were possible using gigabit ethernet) I would like to ask if have my solution may be not as good as I think it is to ensure the least performance hit on thread #1 and if you think there would better designs for that? At least I am unable to think of another solution that is not using locks on the data itself (avoiding the pipe, but potentially locking thread #1) or a shared list implementation using rwlock, with possible reader starvation.

There are scenarios where packets are larger, but we currently use the mode for performance measuring where 1 Streams sends exactly 1000 packets per second. We currently want to ensure version 2.0 at least is possible to work with 12 Streams (hence 12000 packets per second), however previously the server was able to manage 84 Streams.

In the future I would like to add other milestone timestamps to thread #1, e.g. inside `modifyPacket()` (there are multiple steps) and before `sendPacket()`.

I have tried tinkering with the `current_time()` function, mostly trying to remove it to save time by just storing the value of `clock_gettime()`, but in my simple test program the `current_time()` function always beat the clock_gettime.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

> if you think there would better designs for that?

The short answer is to use [Data Plane Development Kit (DPDK)](http://dpdk.org) with its design patterns and libraries. It might be quite a learning curve, but in terms of performance it is the best solution at the moment. It is free and open source (BSD license).

A bit more detailed answer:

> the data struct is written into a pipe

Since thread #1 and #2 are the threads of the same process, it would be much faster to pass data using shared memory, not pipes. Just like you used between threads #2 and #3.

> thread #2 uses a given aggregation function that stores the data in another place in memory

Those two threads seems unnecessary. Thread #2 can read data passed by thread #1, aggregate and send it out?

> I am unable to think of another solution that is not using locks on the data itself

Have a look at the lockless queues which are called ["rings" in DPDK](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/prog_guide/ring_lib.html). The idea is to have a common [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) between threads and use lockless algorithms to enqueue/dequeue to/from the buffer.

> We currently want to ensure version 2.0 at least is possible to work with 12 Streams (hence 12000 packets per second), however previously the server was able to manage 84 Streams.

**Measure the performance and find the bottlenecks** (seems your are still not 100% sure what is the bottleneck in the code).

Just for the reference, Intel publishes the [performance reports for DPDK](https://fast.dpdk.org/doc/perf/DPDK_18_02_Intel_NIC_performance_report.pdf). Those reference numbers for L3 forwarding (i.e. routing) are up to 30 million packet per second.

Sure, you might have less powerful processor and NIC, but few millions packets per second are reachable quite easily using the right techniques.